# Eclipse on Linux some fonts are too small (git staging, dialog, outline, problems etc)

Tags: eclipse, hidpi

Well, I am using Spring Tools Suite 4.12 (based on Eclipse 4.11) one Deepin OS (which is debian based).

My screen is 3K, (2880x1620).  Deepin allows me to scale the screen, so my display is set to native resolution, and in Deepin, I set the scale to 1.5 so after scale it should be similar to 1080p.

It works for most applications, except STS (Eclipse 4.11).

Most views in STS looks good similar to 1080p, but there are still some views with tiny fonts, such as git staging, problem:

[image]

[image]

Any way to fix that in FONT settings or modifying the theme css file?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a full day to find a fix.

I have fonts being too small on Windows. Exactly like you, package, outline etc way too small for my eyes.

Install plug in http://eclipse.jeeeyul.net/update/

Then in Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Jeeeyul -> Custom CSS

Copy paste this, Apply

```
.MPart  {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 12;
    color: #000000;
}

.MPart Tree  {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 12;
    color: #000000;
}

.MPartStack {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 12;
}
```

If using EGIT, you will also need to set Appearance -> Colors And Font -> Uncommited Change Font to the same
font family and size as above.

Jeeeyul plug-in also has nice little features to customize the tabs.

Create a new preset, save it and restart Eclipse to make sure everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am on Linux.  After I applied the fix, some of the views still have problem, but it's better than before.  I have since switched to VS Code.  VS code has no problem with 3k display.

Comment: @the-mw Yes. I noticed my code completion window is still using small fonts. I need eclipse for my workflow. So i don't have a choice. I will update answer when I find something.

Comment: Thanks.  I like eclipse a lot, it's a feature rich IDE, but unfortunately, I had to switch to VS Code... there a lot of features are missing from VS Code, but I had no choice.