# how to change DVT eclipse menu font-size

Tags: eclipse, verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I need to change DVT eclipse menu size. also in properties view and Project Explorer.

High DPI make them larger than the code font size.

Although [this soultion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968641/eclipse-on-linux-some-fonts-are-too-small-git-staging-dialog-outline-problem) did work it was complicated and change only the Project Explorer (without Menu and Project)

```
DVT Version - dvt_eclipse_20.1.37-e46
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in DVT "Themes" [documentation page](https://dvteclipse.com/documentation/sv/Themes.html?highlight=font).

To change the fonts, please go to **Window > Preferences > DVT > Themes**.

You will find there the option to change both the Editor Font and the UI Font (the second one is what you are looking for)

[image]